# Why Hashable protocol forces variable to be comply with Equatable protocol?

Tags: swift, xcode

My confusion starts with the below code.

```
class Student : Hashable {
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(firstName)
        hasher.combine(lastName)
        hasher.combine(stateName)
        hasher.combine(villageName)
    }
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var stateName: String?
    var villageName: String?
}
```

So far as my knowledge on Hashable, it makes the variable uniquely identifiable by mapping it to some key, However, I don't foresee any reason which should force the variable to be equatable always.
If there is no comparison operation to be done in the class created above then it looks un-necessary to put an extra protocol "Equatable"? Is there any reason which I could not visualize?

Comment: What would you do wish a struct that's hashable but not equatable? You can see that two students hash the same (or don't), but then what would you do with this information?

Comment: I believe the underlying confusion is that hashes are not "uniquely identifiable." Two values can have the same hash but not be equal. This is a fundamental fact of any fixed-size hash that can handle arbitrary-length input; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: @RobNapier thanks, this is something I was missing,  something that I never thought of , learned after so many downvotes.

Comment: It was a good, non-obvious question (otherwise the accepted answer wouldn't have that many upvotes), don't know why anybody would downvote it. I deleted my wrong answer but my suggestion still stands, unless you really have to use a `class`, using a `struct` means you won't have to implement those functions yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I agree , thanks @EmilioPelaez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because any use of hashing to locate objects (e.g. in a `Dictionary`) needs to handle hashing collisions - that is when different (unequal) objects have the same hash value.

When that happens, there needs to be a way to check objects for equality.

Comment: thanks  yeah something  I never thought of, Learnt after so many downvotes